# Does getConnection always open a new connection?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource

I have found this method in a Java file and I am wondering what's happening here? Does this really work? I think this method does nothing because the getConnection()-method creates a new connection and then it gets closed. Am I correct?

```
public void closeAllConnections()
    {
        for(String db : this.dbList)
            try {
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) this.applicationContext.getBean(db+"DataSource"); 
                ds.getConnection().close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //...
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how your DataSource is defined.

If it uses connection pooling it can reuse existing connection

for example see [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/connpoca.htm) explanation

> Connection pooling in the JDBC 2.0 extension API is a framework for
>   caching database connections. This allows reuse of physical
>   connections and reduced overhead for your application.